Having two tab bars with expo route
I am new to react native and I am trying to build an application.
I would like to use expo router for navigation because I saw it was easier to set up than react navigation.
This is what I am trying to achieve with my navigation :
double tab bars
I saw it was possible online but after trying a lot I cannot make this work.
Is there a way to have two tab bars with expo router ?
I tried to have a (tabs) folder, being my lower tab bar. And in this (tabs) folder I have another (tabs) folder being my top tabs bar.
arborescence

You need to look into nested navigator stacks. Running 2 tabs at the same time can not be done but, initialising the Bottom tab and in one of those pages initialising the second tab can be done!

I would suggest creating the Bottom tab navigator first and in one of those pages you can use the following (or some other elements, whatever you prefer)

Tabs

